# dynamic datatype for List cause app crash

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dynamic, xamarin.ios

I have two listviews (Normal List and Grouping list) in ViewModel, and at UI I want to use one listview.
So I am trying to use dynamic datatype for runtime list allocation.

```
private dynamic commonList { get; set; }
public dynamic CommonList
{
    get
    {
        return commonList;
    }
    set
    {
        commonList = value;
            
    }
}

ItemsGrouped = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, ListItem>>(List);
commonList = new ExpandoObject();
commonList = ItemsGrouped;
```

This works fine, but when I am trying to set another list to same dyanamic datatype then it causing issue.

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(List);
commonList = new ExpandoObject();
commonList = Items;
```

Here App is crashing with Error:

> dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's has hidden visibility or is defined in more than one translation unit. They should all have public visibility. N10__cxxabiv116__shim_type_infoE, id, N10__cxxabiv117__pbase_type_infoE.

> Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
> Native stack trace:
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
> 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d03ab1 _CFThrowFormattedException + 194
> 3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d06cc6 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:].cold.3 + 38
> 4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c4a1c4 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 164
> 5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c5f6d4 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 52
> 6   CRMM.iOS                            0x0000000100c4b280 xamarin_convert_managed_to_nsarray_with_func + 464
> 7   CRMM.iOS                            0x0000000100c4da18 xamarin_managed_string_array_to_nsarray + 40
> 8   CRMM.iOS                            0x0000000100c4dafc xamarin_managed_array_to_nsarray + 124
> 9   CRMM.iOS                            0x0000000100c498be _ZL33xamarin_marshal_return_value_implP9_MonoTypePKcP10MonoObjectbP11_MonoMethodP17MethodDescriptionPj + 558
> 10  CRMM.iOS                            0x0000000100c4963a xamarin_marshal_return_value + 106
> 11  CRMM.iOS                            0x0000000100c595bb _ZL20marshal_return_valuePvPKcmS_P9_MonoTypebP11_MonoMethodP17MethodDescriptionPj + 1915
> 12  CRMM.iOS                            0x0000000100c50fe0 xamarin_invoke_trampoline + 7984
> 13  CRMM.iOS                            0x0000000100c58adb xamarin_arch_trampoline + 107
> 14  CRMM.iOS                            0x0000000100c59ce2 xamarin_x86_64_common_trampoline + 118
> 15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48257490 -[UITableView _updateIndexTitlesFromDataSource] + 149
> 16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4825756f -[UITableView _updateIndex] + 165
> 17  CRMM.iOS                            0x0000000100c59e69 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
> 18  ???                                 0x0000000108d10a0a 0x0 + 4442884618

Comment: `dynamic` isn't usually a great choice in AOT scenarios, but: in the cases shown, you've only shown you assigning to a private property; is that property bound to anything? I wouldn't expect it to explode until you try *consuming* that `dynamic` type, which the code here: doesn't show (well, it does in the stack-trace, but: the stack-trace doesn't seem to match the code shown much)

Comment: Yes, I have Updated Question. Please recheck. Thank you for comment

Comment: Preferably don't use `dynamic` at all. And why are you doing `commonList = new ExpandoObject();` if you immediately throw it away the next line? I would suggest you do a course on C#. You seem to be in way over your head.

Comment: ok, I will remove that ExpandoObject, Can you please suggest me instead of dynamic, which property should I use to maintain single list.

Comment: You could [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin doesn't support `dynamic`.

This isn't necessarily a limitation of Xamarin, but a limitation of the native platforms.

For example, iOS requires its apps to be Ahead Of Time (AOT) compiled; code cannot be generated during runtime. This is a security requirement from Apple to prevent apps from generating malicious code on your phone during runtime.

Here's the official Microsoft docs for more information:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations#no-dynamic-code-generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations#no-dynamic-code-generation?WT.mc_id=mobile-0000-bramin)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brandon for answer, do you have any solution for showing grouped list and normal list in single Listview?

Comment: @SumitPathak you can always change the binding context, doesn't need to be the same property that is bound.